# matplotlib in python, how to only increase canvas size?

Tags: python, canvas, matplotlib

I'm using

```
self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
```

or

```
self.fig = plt.figure(figsize=(17, 17))  
self.ax = self.fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1], frameon=False)
```

Although both of them increase the size of the canvas, they really just 'stretch' the canvas, as well as everything inside it.

What I want is a real enlarged canvas (most probably with the window enlarged), with objects inside remaining the same sizes, so that a canvas could have more details in one scope.

Comment: I was going to suggest a solution with a `resize_event` and found the following, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329151/automatically-changing-view-bounds-on-resize-matlotlib which I think is exactly what you need? For some reason the resize event doesn't work in my version of matplotlib so I cannot test this.

Comment: There's no backend-independent way to change the size of the window itself, although there are backend-specific solutions. What backend are you using?